# Scapy: How to check if ping using srp1 (using Layer 2) was successful

Tags: python, hex, decode, ping, scapy

I use the scapy module to create packages and want to send them over layer 2 since this is much more performant as L3.
My packages look like this:

```
resp = srp1(Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.0.11")/ICMP(), verbose=True)
```

'resp' is a list of the result/answer. resp[0] shows the entire content. But since i send ethers the result is in hex.

How can i check if the ping was successfull. Simply convert/decode it doesn't work because the type is:

```
<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>
```

Is there a function provided by scapy which does the job or at least shows the result human readable in order to validate it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resp.summary()
```

Or

```
repr(resp)
```

Or

```
resp.show()
```

They are ordered by verbosity. Their output are all different

You should read scapy's doc over
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I also found this

```resp[0].summary()
```

which shows the packet in layers.

Comment: `srp1` does not return a list so I'm assuming you made an error in your first post and are using `srp` instead or similar..

Comment: The return value of ```srp1``` is a ```<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>```. But you can call the different layers using ```resp[x].summary()```. For example an ethernet frame which contains an IP packet containing a ICMP packet in its payload can be viewed separately. ```resp[0]``` would show everything, ```resp[2]``` only the ICMP part. Therefore you are right, its not a list. My mistake, badly worded.